# Cant use arrows inside input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i did not make this script, but its a posting form, simple just html,

This is the html in input

```
<input class="text_box" type="text" name="title" id="title" size="19" value="Title"  onkeydown="SpecialReplace(this)" onkeyup="SpecialReplace(this)" onblur="SpecialReplace(this)" onclick="SpecialReplace(this)"/>
```

And this is the SpecialReplace() function

```
function SpecialReplace(o)
{
      o.value=o.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÜüñÑ¨´,.¿?%&$!¡ªº#"()-_\/]/g,'');
}
```

I try to use arrows, to go to a specific letter to "edit" but i cant use the arrows in the input, why??

and how can i solve this?

Comment: When the value is replaced, the cursor is moved to the end. I would check the key that was pressed and only do the replace if the key wasn't an arrow key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why all these inline handlers if you are using jQuery?

Anyway, here's how you could do it:

HTML

```
<input class="text_box" type="text" name="title" id="title" size="19" value="Title">
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    //you have to escaped the - character in a character class
    var cleanRx = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÜüñÑ¨´,.¿?%&$!¡ªº#"()\-_\/]/g;

    $('#title').keyup(function (e) {
        var which = e.which;

        //avoid useless replacements when <- and -> keys are pressed
        if (which === 39 || which === 37) return;

        this.value = this.value.replace(cleanRx, '');

    }).trigger('keyup'); //perform replacement on initial content (remove if uneeded)

});
```

Comment: I did not write this... I just need to fix this.. cause actually works, this is just an issue.

Comment: @MonchoChavez Well it should work the way you want with what I provided.

Comment: Yep it does, do you know "cmd + a" code, i use this to select all, but this command is not working... i guess as 39 and 37 this command has a value, where can i check this?